# How to use Picat to create CNF files from Minizinc files?

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc, sat, picat

I'm interested in counting the number of solutions a problem have (not enumerating the solutions). For that, I have tools that uses [CNF](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/cnf/cnf.html) files. I want to convert [Minizinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) files (mzn or Flatzinc fzn format) and convert it to CNF.

I learned [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/) has the ability to "dump" a CNF file after loading the constraints. Moreover, Picat has a clever Module that interprets basic Flatzinc files. I modified the module [fzn_picat_sat.pi](http://picat-lang.org/flatzinc/fzn_picat_sat.pi) to "dump" the CNF file. So, what I do is that I convert a Minizinc file to Flatzinc using mzn2fzn, then I try to convert it to CNF using my (slightly) [modified version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc3pxn9m2l2v1sa/fzn_picat_sat.pi?dl=0) of fzn_picat_sat.pi.

What I want : I expect Picat to load the Flatzinc files and dump an appropriate CNF file. If the original problems has X solutions, I expect the corresponding CNF to have X solutions.

What happens : Most Flatzinc files I tried worked just fine. But some seem to give unwanted results. For example, [the following mzn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pu0zo6blbtbzxzh/Sequence.mzn?dl=0) translate to [this Flatzinc file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0leaq02ne58nxu/Sequence.fzn?dl=0). That file has only 211 solutions, but the [CNF file dumped](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5khzpdzz17l8zs/Sequence.cnf?dl=0) by Picat has over 130k solutions. Many SAT solvers can show that the CNF file has over 211 solutions (for example [cryptominisat](https://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat5/) with the option `--maxsol`). Weirdly, when I ask Picat to solve the Flatzinc file without translating to CNF, Picat does find only 211 solutions. The problem seems to be somewhere in the translation. Finally, even if the CNF file has the good number of solutions using Picat, I do receive an error `% fzn_interpretation_error`.

If anyone tried something like that and succeeded, or if anyone knows how to translate from a CP (constraint programming) language to CNF, that would be much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: 1) Exactly how do you translate the ,mzn file to .fzn? Are you including Picat's global definitions when doing this? 2) How do you get a sat solver to generate all solutions?

Comment: @hakank: [cryptominisat](https://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat5/) has a `--maxsol` option to enumerate solutions. Otherwise, one could add a clause with all inverted literals of the solution to forbid this solution to be found again.

Comment: Could it be that the Picat translation adds auxiliary variables, and the resulting solutions differ only in these auxiliary variables?

Comment: One way to do to enumerate all solutions is exactly as @AxelKemper says and use --maxsol of cryptominisat. Many (if not all) of SAT solvers will have an option like this.

Comment: @hakank I answered to the second question with my previous comment. For the first question, as specified in the question, I use mzn2fzn, wich seems to be a know tool since it is mentionned in the file fzn_picat_sat.pi. And if I'm not mistaken, you are part of the team that made this module possible, therefore I hope what I say is understandable.

Comment: @AxelKemper Maybe Picat adds auxilary variables that changes the number of solutions. But I can give multiple example very similar to the one above where the resulting CNF works just fine and gives the expected number of solutions. Maybe I misunderstand some things about all this, it is very possible. But even with added variables, I would hope I'd get the expected number of solutions. So, if this is the case, is there any way to know which variables should be removed when I'm counting the solutions?

Comment: @AxelKemper Thanks for the tip about cryptominisat. The SAT solvers I tested (minisat, lingeling, glucose) don't support all solutions what I know. I also found  bc_minisat_all.

Comment: @Exeloz The reason `fzn_interpretation_error` is thrown is because fzn_picat_sat  try to translate an MiniZInc output variable to CNF, but that requires that the variables are instantiated and this is not the case when using `[dump]`. I'm not sure if this influence the rest of the translation. Though I tested with a simple 8 queens model and got 288 solutions instead of 92 so something is strange. Can you link to a MiniZinc model were you get the correct solution with a SAT solver?

Comment: @hakank Actually, I can. I did test the 8-queens using non binary variables in the Minizinc file. Here is a simple [mzn file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dezd1qu668j2kr/nqueens-int.mzn?dl=0), and the corresponding [fzn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb0tt9ly1nsrv0r/nqueens-int.fzn?dl=0), and the corresponding [CNF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmhcyug7pu0mcbt/nqueens-int.cnf?dl=0) given by Picat having 92 solution.

Comment: @Exeloz Thanks for the queens model. I can confirm that the CNF version yield 92 solutions. However, the CNF for this model (http://hakank.org/minizinc/queens4,mzn ) (using `all_different` constraints) give 288 solutions. It seems that the all_different constraint give some extra internal variables.

Comment: @Exeloz Regarding the `fzn_interpretation_error`: If you comment out the calls to `fzn_output` in the Picat program, the error message should go away.

Comment: @hakank Regarding the error, thank you for the tip. As for the queen model, I agree my model was sub-optimal in many ways as I did not use any global constraint. I tried to avoid this constraints since the header of fzn_picat_sat.pi warns that alldifferent/1 should not be decomposed by mzn2fzn. I would like to also point out that I do not use any global constraints in Sequence.mzn linked in the the question. So even if alldifferent/1 give some extra internal variables, I do not understand about Sequence.mzn. But there is definitely something going on here

Comment: @Exeloz I think Mikael's answer is on the spot regarding internal variables. In the Sequence case there is a lot of extra variables created in the FlatZinc file (the one with `var_is_introduced`), though the FlatZinc solvers only outputs solutions where  the variables tagged as `output_array` are different. I don't know how to avoid handling the internal variables in the CNF file (well, they are part of the model so they should be included in the model) or identify them in some intelligent way.

Comment: @hakank Fair enough, it does make a lot of sense, thats for sure. But I do hope to find a tool that could do the job, but that will be for another question, eventually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220099/discussion-between-hakank-and-exeloz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Axel Kemper, MiniZinc may add additional variables that should not be used to differentiate multiple solutions. As a simple example, consider the following (artificial) MiniZinc model

```
predicate separated(var int: x, var int: y) = 
    let {
      var int: z
    } in
     x < z /\ z < y;
     
var 1..10: x;
var 1..10: y;

constraint separated(x, y);

solve satisfy;
```

Here the predicate `separated` adds another variable that is just used as a witness that there is some number between x and y (the predicate is equivalent to `abs(x-y)>0`).

The model has 36 solutions (`1,3`, `1,4`, ..., `8,10`). However, if you consider the solution `3,8`, there are 5 different choices of z that makes the predicate true. In general, a user is most likely only interested in solutions that differ in the output variables.

When translating the above MiniZinc to CNF the predicate internal z-variable will not be distinguished from the "real" problem variables x and y. For counting the solutions, you would need to distinguish the literals that correspond to the domains of output variables in the model, and to instruct the SAT solver to only consider two solutions different if those literals are different (not sure if that is a feature that is available).

Comment: Actually, I have [tools to only consider a subset of variables](https://github.com/meelgroup/ganak) when counting the solutions. (This is not offered in a solver that I know of). So, if there was a way to know what variables are the output variables, I'd be able to do whatever I'm trying to do. Do you know of any way to do this? Thanks for the explanation by the way.

Comment: This answers makes sense and with a very compelling model. I appreciate the time you took. I will accept this answer and still hope to find a way to pick the right variables while doing the counting.

Comment: Thanks. As I have never used Picat myself, I can't help you with that.

Comment: @Exeloz output variables are conveniently marked as such with an annotation in the FlatZinc file that is generated by the mzn2fzn compiler (or minizinc). You can check Picat parser to find out whether it retains those tags. If not, you can create internal data structures to remember them and then use them as it pleases you.